# The type constructor "..." would escape its scope when using first class modules

Tags: types, module, ocaml, typeerror, first-class-modules

Given a simple factory:

```
module type Factory  = sig type t val create : unit -> t end
module FactoryImpl : Factory = struct 
   type t = string
   let create: unit -> t = fun ()  -> "aaa" 
end 
let factory: (module Factory) = (module FactoryImpl)
let f = let module F = (val factory) in F.create ()
```

Compiler complains:

```
This has type:
F.t
But somewhere wanted:
F.t
The type constructor F.t would escape its scope
```

I am quite new to OCaml modules and not sure how to tell compiler that `f` is of type `Factory.t`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem here is that `F.create ()` produces a value of type `F.t`, so `f` should have type `F.t`, but that is impossible because `F` is not bound outside the `let module` that binds `F`.

If you extend the scope of `F` to be global, the program will type check:

```
module type Factory = sig
  type t
  val create : unit -> t
end

module FactoryImpl : Factory = struct
  type t = string
  let create: unit -> t = fun () -> "aaa"
end

let factory: (module Factory) = (module FactoryImpl)

module F = (val factory)

let f = F.create ()
```

Note that `Factory.t` is not a valid type, as there is no module bound to the name `Factory`. Modules and module types are in separate namespaces.