# Parametrically polymorphic modules

Tags: ocaml

Here is a simple OCaml module type for a monad:

```ml
module type Monad = sig
  type 'a t
  val return : 'a -> 'a t
  val bind : 'a t -> ('a -> 'b t) -> 'b t
end
```

I can instantiate this with any particular monad, such as the reader monad for some type `r`:

```ml
module Reader_monad : Monad = struct
  type 'a t = r -> 'a
  let return a = fun _ -> a
  let bind o f = fun x -> f (o x) x
end
```

And I can parametrize it over the type `r` by using a functor:

```ml
module type Readable = sig type r end
module Reader (R : Readable) : Monad = struct
  type 'a t = R.r -> 'a
  let return a = fun _ -> a
  let bind o f = fun x -> f (o x) x
end
```

However, the latter approach requires that I instantiate different instances of the functor for different types `r`.  Is there any way to define a "parametrically polymorphic" module of type `Monad` that would give parametrically polymorphic functions like `return : 'a -> ('r -> 'a)`?

I think can get more or less what I want with a separate module type for "families of monads":

```ml
module type Monad_family = sig
  type ('c, 'a) t
  val return : 'a -> ('c, 'a) t
  val bind : ('c, 'a) t -> ('a -> ('c, 'b) t) -> ('c, 'b) t
end

module Reader_family : Monad_family = struct
  type ('c, 'a) t = 'c -> 'a
  let return a = fun _ -> a
  let bind o f = fun x -> f (o x) x
end
```

But if I have a substantial library of general facts about monads, this would require modifying it everywhere manually to use families.  And then some monads are parametrized by a pair of types (although I suppose that could be encoded by a product type), etc.  So I would rather avoid having to do it this way.

If this isn't directly possible, is there at least a way to instantiate the module `Reader` locally inside a parametrically polymorphic function?  I thought I might be able to do this with first-class modules, but my naive attempt

```ml
let module M = Reader(val (module struct type r = int end) : Readable) in M.return "hello";;
```

produces the error message

```
Error: This expression has type string M.t
       but an expression was expected of type 'a
       The type constructor M.t would escape its scope
```

which I don't understand.  Isn't the type `M.t` equal to `int -> string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the same issue as [The type constructor "..." would escape its scope when using first class modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254916/the-type-constructor-would-escape-its-scope-when-using-first-class-modules), where the module `M` doesn't live long enough. If you instead wrote

```
# module M = Reader(struct type r = int end);;
# M.return "hello";;
- : string M.t = <fun>
```

then this would work fine.

Separately, the `Reader` functor loses some type equalities that you might want. You can restore them by defining it as such:

```
module Reader (R : Readable) : Monad with type 'a t = R.r -> 'a = struct
  type 'a t = R.r -> 'a
  let return a = fun _ -> a
  let bind o f = fun x -> f (o x) x
end
```

Comment: Ah, I see!  OCaml needs help to realize that the type `M.t -> string` is in fact equal to `int -> string`.  It works if instead of `M.return "hello"` I write `M.return "hello" : int -> string`, or if I fully execute the monadic computation like `M.return "hello" 4` inside the let-binding.

Comment: (*And* if I remove the `: Monad` on the definition of `Reader`, so that I guess the actual definitions are exposed rather than just the interface.)

Comment: Ah, but alas, this doesn't seem to work for an actual *polymorphic* function, or if it does I can't figure out the syntax.  Writing `let f (s:'a) = let module M = Reader(val (module struct type r = 'a end) : Readable) in (M.return s : 'a -> string)` gives "Error: The type variable 'a is unbound in this type declaration."

Comment: @MikeShulman I think syntactically you can use a locally abstract type, like `let f (type a) (s : a) = ...` but this still runs into some type errors.

Comment: Oh, it's because I was being dumb: the argument of `return` is the thing to return, not the thing to read.  This works: `let f (type a) (s:'b) = let module M = Reader(val (module struct type r = a end) : Readable) in (M.return s : a -> 'b)`.